# Kie Execution Server produces StartException when deploying kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7.war

Tags: java, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have been trying to deploy my rules from Drools Workbench to the Kie Exectution server but to no avail. I am using Wildfly 8.2.1.Final, with drools 6.3.0.Final, and JDK 1.7.0_79. I have ant Environment variable set, as well as the maven one.

Below is the error from the server.log file:

2015-11-04 13:13:24,342 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "kie-server.war" (runtime-name: "kie-server.war")
2015-11-04 13:13:42,440 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Users/mvschalkwyk.PRINCIPA/Documents/Programming/Guvnor/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/content/kie-server.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2015-11-04 13:13:42,444 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/Users/mvschalkwyk.PRINCIPA/Documents/Programming/Guvnor/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/content/kie-server.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2015-11-04 13:13:42,450 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/Users/mvschalkwyk.PRINCIPA/Documents/Programming/Guvnor/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/content/kie-server.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2015-11-04 13:13:42,451 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /C:/Users/mvschalkwyk.PRINCIPA/Documents/Programming/Guvnor/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/content/kie-server.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2015-11-04 13:13:42,705 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "kie-server.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:668) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:278)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

2015-11-04 13:13:42,711 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kie-server.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"kie-server.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
2015-11-04 13:13:43,313 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7.war" (runtime-name: "kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7.war")
2015-11-04 13:13:43,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "kie-server.war" (runtime-name : "kie-server.war")
2015-11-04 13:13:43,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "kie-server.war"

Please can someone help me in rectifying this error?

Comment: I do have a user with kie-server role.

Comment: My PATH variables are also set to their corresponding \bin directories.

Comment: If i use kie-server-6.3.0.Final-webc.war then i am able to deploy the execution server but then when i try to deploy from WB i do not get an endpoint for my containers.

Comment: And when i try to list all the containers through the ES(http://localhost:8080/kie-server-6.3.0.Final-webc/services/rest/server/containers) it returns an empty list of containers.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to Wildfly 8.1.0.Final and also downgraded drools to 6.2.0.Final(this includes the workbench and the Execution server) and now it works.

I used this thread for reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/drools-setup/VQ-SSDD3Dp8